# Windows form getting minimized

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, winforms

I have 2 windows forms and from the **first form** when a button is clicked one validation is happening which is happening outside,using another script ('PML'-Programmable Macro Language) and i am getting back the control to the **first form** and  trying to show the **second form** from there, but the second form is getting minimized. Is there a way to fix it?

```
        SpecModifierForm specModifierForm = new SpecModifierForm();
        specModifierForm.Show();
        specModifierForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        specModifierForm.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Please consider posting a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `specModifier.ShowDialog();`